# How do I draw multiple SDL_rects to the screen in sdl2?

Tags: c, sdl-2

So I have this function that takes a rect, RGB, alpha values and a char which determines if it will fill the rect or not.

```
void make_rect(SDL_Rect rect, SDL_Renderer * renderer, int r, int g, int b, int a,  char flag)
{
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, r, g, b, a);
    if(drawmd == 'f')
    {
        SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rect);
    }
    else if(drawmd == 'd')
    {
        SDL_RenderDrawRect(renderer, &rect);
    }

    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}
```

I call the function twice with different rects:
rect_1:

```
SDL_Rect rect;
rect.x = 241;
rect.y = 389;
rect.w = 104;
rect.h = 69;
int r = 32;
int g = 186;
int b = 247;
int a = 255;
char dm = 'f'
make_rect(rect, renderer, r, g, b, a, dm);
```

and the same with different values and names not listed here.

All of these variables are within bounds and I don't get a compilation error it only draws one of the rects.

Comment: May not be your issue, but, you probably want to _remove_ the call to `SDL_RenderPresent` from your function. It redraws the _screen_ each time, so a bit slow. I'd do all drawing calls _first_ and then make a single call to `SDL_RenderPresent` at the end. You might want: `make_rect(...); make_rect(...); ... SDL_RenderPresent(...);`